# Parsing the string and populate the map

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this:

```
command1 -keep -path { {path1} }  { {./input.doc} }
```

I wanted to parse the above line and collect the information into a map where value would be contents of -path option and key would be everything else. The format of the string would be fixed that after -path there would be two opening and two closes brackets. In this case,

key would be:

```
command1 -keep { {./input.doc} }
```

Value would be:

```
path1
```

I was doing it using brute force method as like:

Get the position of -path.

Get the position of second closing bracket.

Little more processing and create two substring of -path and remaining else with above two positions. Like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

int main() {
  std::string s1 = "command1 -keep -path { {path1} }  { {./input.doc} }";

  std::size_t found = s1.find("-path");
  std::size_t closeBracesPos = s1.find_first_of("}",s1.find_first_of("}")+1);
  std::string preS1                  = s1.substr(0, found);
  std::string postS1                 = s1.substr(closeBracesPos+1);
  std::string pathStr                = s1.substr(found+1, s1.size() - preS1.size() - postS1.size());

  std::size_t pathStrOpeningBracePos = pathStr.find_last_of("{");
  std::size_t pathStrClosingBracePos = pathStr.find_first_of("}");
  std::string pathStrOpeningBrace = pathStr.substr(0, pathStrOpeningBracePos);
  std::string pathStrClosingBrace = pathStr.substr(pathStrClosingBracePos);
  std::string pathNames           = pathStr.substr(pathStrOpeningBracePos+1, pathStr.size()-pathStrOpeningBrace.size()-pathStrClosingBrace.size()-1);

  std::string remainingStr = preS1 + " " + postS1;
  std::cout << "PATH NAMES :" << pathNames << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Remaining :" << remainingStr << std::endl;
}
```

This seems little rusty to me. Can we discuss other methods to extract this information?

Comment: Are you familiar with [finite state automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)? You can define individual states to extract key and value. Basically you read through the input and keep record of what entity you are currently looking at.

Comment: @bitmask, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know it in theory. Never had any experience of using that in practical.

Comment: It would be nice to see your solution so that we have a frame of reference for what you mean.

Comment: @cigien, There you go. I have edited my answer.

Comment: That's much better, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regex, you might do:

```
std::string s1 = "command1 -keep -path { {path1} }  { {./input.doc} }";
std::regex pattern{R"((.*)-path \{ \{([^}]*)\} \}(.*))"};

std::smatch obj;
if (std::regex_match(s1, obj, pattern))
{
    std::string key = obj[1].str() + obj[3].str();
    std::string value = obj[2].str();

    // ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf0d48f6db0e6cd)